# image button on click image change

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an image button on my form which opens a modal popup dialog on click. The onmouseout, onmouseover, onfocus, onblur events are set in the skin file.

What I want to achieve is, when the modal popup dialog is open the 'image button' image should be like it is on onmouseover and onfocus image set in the skin.

But I am not able to achieve this by adding the following js i.e.

```
$("#btnAdd").src=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_on.png';
```

(The above js I have written in the js function which opens up the modal dialog)

since, on the fire of onblur/onmouseout event which happens since the focus shifts to the modal dialog, the image set due to above js is lost.

What can be the possible solution for this? Please inform me since I need to integrate this asap.

**skin file :**

```
<asp:ImageButton  SkinId="Add" alt="Add" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Add_item_over.png"
onmouseout="this.src=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_over.png';"
onmouseover="this.src=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_on.png';" 
onfocus="this.src=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_on.png';" 
onblur="this.src=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_over.png';"/>
```

Comment: Try using `$('#<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>')`

Comment: I have no issue in finding the control btnAdd since I have kept its clientid mode as static

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the property `src` of a `jQuery element`.
If you wan't access to the HTMLDOMElement, you need to write `$('#btnAdd')[0]`.

Moreover, if your `btnAdd` is an `<button>` tag, you need to do something like:

```
$("#btnAdd").css({
 backgroundImage: url(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_on.png';)
});
```

In case of an `img` tag

```
$("#btnAdd").attr('src', window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'ClientWeb/Images/Add_item_on.png');
```

Comment: I had added the above img tag jquery, it changes the image as well, but as I had specified in my question, since the focus shifts from button to the modal dialog,,  the image button retains its original image.